# Replace only inside tag brackets

Tags: php, regex

I want the regex to use in preg_replace() to replace text only inside a 
tag (between "<" and ">"), without affect the text out of angle brackets limit. 
Like this example:

```
$html = '<div class="REPLACE_ME" id="my_id">this REPLACE_ME cannot be replaced</div>';
$html = preg_replace('/\bREPLACE_ME\b/', 'REPLACED', $html);
```

then, the result expected in $html variable must be like this:

```
<div class="REPLACED" id="my_id">this REPLACE_ME cannot be replaced</div>
```

The regex cannot be around the quotes, because I have other variants like:

```
<REPLACE_ME>this REPLACE_ME cannot be replaced</REPLACE_ME>
<div REPLACE_ME="my_attribute">this REPLACE_ME cannot be replaced</div>
```

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/597122

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Thank for your tip @rocketest, but this reference don't help-me, because I don't want to find only matches tags.

Comment: Hey Rodrigo, it was a tongue-in-cheek posting, but the underlying point is this: it doesn't SPECIFICALLY answer your question, but the overall answer is ---> Do NOT parse HTML with REGEX. You simply cannot do it without creating black holes. It's a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex:

```
<[^>]*\KREPLACE_ME(?=[^>]*?>)
```

Replacement string:

```
REPLACED
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nO4kH0/1)

PHP code would be,

```
<?php
$mystring = <<<'EOT'
<div class="REPLACE_ME" id="my_id">this REPLACE_ME cannot be replaced</div>
<REPLACE_ME>this REPLACE_ME cannot be replaced</REPLACE_ME>
<div REPLACE_ME="my_attribute">this REPLACE_ME cannot be replaced</div>
EOT;
echo preg_replace('~<[^>]*\KREPLACE_ME(?=[^>]*?>)~', 'REPLACED', $mystring);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
<div class="REPLACED" id="my_id">this REPLACE_ME cannot be replaced</div>
<REPLACED>this REPLACE_ME cannot be replaced</REPLACED>
<div REPLACED="my_attribute">this REPLACE_ME cannot be replaced</div>
```

**Explanation:**

- `<` Matches the lesser than `<` symbol.
- `[^>]*` Matches any character not of `>` zero or more times.
- `\K` Discards the previously matched characters. So from `<` upto the `REPLACE_ME` string would be discarded.
- `REPLACE_ME` Matches the string `REPLACE_ME`.
- `(?=[^>]*?>)` Lookahead asserts that the following  characters  must be anything not of `>` symbol followed by `>`. This ensures that the matched string `REPLACE_ME` is within `<>` block.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps something like [this](http://regex101.com/r/tJ1yD2/2)

I think what you're looking for is a positive lookahead or lookbehind.

So the regex I used is:

```
(?<=<).*?(REPLACE_ME).*?(?=>)
```

The `(?<=<)` means make sure there is a `<` to the left and
then `(?=>)` means make sure there is a `>` to the right

Also, consider using an XML parser. Regex is very limited when it comes to tags like this.

Comment: [Take a look here](http://regex101.com/r/tJ1yD2/3) I'm fairly certain it matches only the `REPLACE_ME`s that are within a tag. Please give me an example where the regex fails.